# Docker build failed to compute cache key

Tags: docker, windows-10, dockerfile, visual-studio-2019, docker-buildkit

I have the below project structure

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         4/22/2021   1:49 PM                App_Start
d-----         3/20/2020   3:35 PM                Areas
d-----          5/4/2021   7:01 PM                bin
d-----         3/20/2020   3:35 PM                Content
d-----          5/4/2021   5:59 PM                Controllers
d-----         3/20/2020   3:35 PM                fonts
d-----         8/20/2020   9:43 PM                obj
d-----          7/9/2020   8:43 PM                Properties
d-----         3/20/2020   3:35 PM                Scripts
d-----         3/20/2020   3:35 PM                Views
-a----          5/4/2021   6:00 PM             46 .dockerignore
-a----          5/4/2021   6:00 PM          45239 foo.csproj
-a----          5/4/2021  11:21 PM           1621 foo.csproj.user
-a----         4/22/2021   1:49 PM            390 ConnectionStrings.config
-a----          5/5/2021  12:17 AM            375 Dockerfile
-a----         3/20/2020   3:35 PM            116 Global.asax
-a----         3/20/2020   3:35 PM            717 Global.asax.cs
-a----         8/13/2020   1:05 PM           1770 NLog.config
-a----         3/20/2020   3:35 PM         159853 NLog.xsd
-a----          5/4/2021   6:00 PM           9217 packages.config
-a----         3/20/2020   3:35 PM          12294 UnityConfiguration30.xsd
-a----          5/4/2021   6:00 PM          29650 Web.config
-a----         3/20/2020   3:35 PM           1308 Web.Debug.config
-a----         3/20/2020   3:35 PM            705 Web.Release.config
```

And I have one directory in `bin directory` that name is `app.publish`.

And my Dockerfile is like below:

```
#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY bin/app.publish .
```

After I run below command to build image from this docker file

```
docker build -t soroshsabz/testcoreservice .
```

I got the below error

```
[+] Building 15.1s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 414B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019         14.9s
 => [1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019@sha256:e1475e80eb3cbdfd81  0.1s
 => => resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019@sha256:e1475e80eb3cbdfd81  0.1s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [2/3] WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot                                                                          0.0s
 => ERROR [3/3] COPY bin/app.publish .                                                                             0.0s
------
 > [3/3] COPY bin/app.publish .:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/bin/app.publish" not found: not found
```

**My question is why I got this error? and how to resolve it?**

I use `Docker Engine Community 20.10.6` on `Windows 10 20H2 19042.964`

I see *[Docker - failed to compute cache key: not found - runs fine in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66146088/1539100)* and [some internal links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63257667/1539100), but does not find any useful things.

I am binging my problem and find some same problem like *[Dockerfile can’t copy specified local directory & file](https://dockerquestions.com/2020/10/16/dockerfile-cant-copy-specified-local-directory-file/)* or *[Windows Docker Dockerfile COPY file inside folder](https://windowsquestions.com/2020/12/17/windows-docker-dockerfile-copy-file-inside-folder/)*.

Comment: What's in the `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: @BMitch You right, and my problem is from dockerignore, thanks a lot, I resolve it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Thanks to BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391438/docker-build-failed-to-compute-cache-key/67391784#comment119117863_67391438), I found my problem. The problem is the dockerignore file contains some pattern that must not match with `COPY` files name.

My problem is the patterns inside the `.dockerignore` file is matched wrongly with `bin/app.publish`. To resolve my problem I just change the pattern in dockerignore.

Specifically, remove the line `**/bin` for `.dockerignore`.

Comment: Next time, I suggest you tell the person who gave you the solution to post it as an answer and accept that instead of posting your own. :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was trying to copy a symlinked directory, created by npm install of a local package.  The symlink pointed to a directory outside the docker context.  I solved the problem by replacing the symlink with a deep copy of the npm package directory, and then docker build worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of some help to others:

I am building a .NET Core application with a dockerfile and had been doing some renaming. I got the "failed to compute cache key" error, because the filenames in the dockerfile no longer matched the new names I had given to the targeted files.

Once I fixed the naming in the dockerfile, everything worded as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the problem was the context path at docker command