# Problem during building Docker container with Angular

Tags: angular, windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My Dockerfile for frontend in Angular:

```yaml
FROM node:18.10.0 as builder
WORKDIR /app/binder-web-frontend
# WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@15

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

ENV PORT 4200

CMD ["ng", "serve"]
```

docker-compose:

```yaml
  angular-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: binder-web-frontend/Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - '4200:4200'
    command: "ng serve --open --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --disable-host-check"
    #
    # volumes: 
      # - ./:/app/binder-web-backend
      # - /binder-web-frontend/node_modules:/app/binder-web-frontend/node_modules
      # - /app/node_modules
```

As you can see in the screenshots, Docker itself is being built in the frontend folder ** /binder-web-frontend **.
When I run **docker-compose ** it doesn't want to copy **`package.json`**.
The file structure is as follows: **Solution/web-frontend/package.json** +**node_modules** are also located here.

[image]

[image]

This is my first experience with Docker and I'm a bit confused.
Thanks in advance for your help/advice.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the error output in plain text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker build failed to compute cache key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391438/docker-build-failed-to-compute-cache-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change docker-compose file to:

```
build:
    context: binder-web-frontend/.
```

it's becuase your docker-copose file and your Dockerfile are not in the same directory.